# Users are not getting stored in Firebase database while images are stored in Firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I work on a project in Android Studio using Firebase authentication. I am not able to store users in Firebase database while user's images are getting stored in Firebase storage. Because of this, it is not going to the next activity and gets stuck.

```
ActivitySetupProfileBinding binding;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseDatabase database;
FirebaseStorage storage;
Uri selectedImage;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivitySetupProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Updating Profile..");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    binding.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent  intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 45);


        }
    });

    binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = binding.nameBox.getText().toString();

            if(name.isEmpty()) {
                binding.nameBox.setError("Name cannot be empty..");
                return;
            }

            dialog.show();
            if(selectedImage !=null) {
                StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Profiles").child(auth.getUid());
                reference.putFile(selectedImage).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    String imageUrl = uri.toString();

                                    String uid = auth.getUid();
                                    String phone = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
                                    String name = binding.nameBox.getText().toString();

                                    User user = new User(uid, name, phone, imageUrl);

                                    database.getReference()
                                            .child("users")
                                            .child(uid)
                                            .setValue(user)
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent (SetupProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    finish();

                                                }
                                            });


                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                });
            } else {
                String uid = auth.getUid();
                String phone = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();

                User user = new User(uid, name, phone, "No Image");

                database.getReference()
                        .child("users")
                        .child(uid)
                        .setValue(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                Intent intent = new Intent (SetupProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(data != null) {
        if(data.getData() != null) {
            binding.imageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
            selectedImage = data.getData();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Hi Alex, Once I execute this code, the It gets stuck at the current activity and does not move to the next activity. It is supposed to store user's information in the Firebase, but it is not happening. I am expecting that Users get stored in the firebase and I can go to next activity. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to implement onFailure, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: I will do that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rules in firebase console for accessing storage.
By default all authenticated users can read and write into storage.
Default rules for storage are:

```
    rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

You should be logged in to firebase before uploading the image.

For testing you can change the line

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

to

```
allow read write;
```

Comment: Thanks SH, I tried allow read, write; Still same.

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved. Actually, In Firebase Database, I changed the location to Europe, rather then default location (US).  Problem solved by changing back the location to US. Thanks !!